How to get a discord.js bot to set a person's username as the author in an embed in a interaction?
I want the author of the interaction to be Mentioned in the author section of the embed but I'm not sure how to do that.
if (interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet").toLowerCase() === ('dog')) {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('favourite pet')
  .setDescription('my favourite pet is also a dog')
  .setColor('Orange')
  .setAuthor(`${interaction.author.username}`)


The above code returns:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

And all I want it to do is to set the author as the person who sent the interaction.

You are trying to access the author property of interaction. This property does not exist on interaction (see docs).
Instead, you can use the user object to get the username.
Updated code:
if (interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet").toLowerCase() === ('dog')) {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('favourite pet')
  .setDescription('my favourite pet is also a dog')
  .setColor('Orange')
  .setAuthor(`${interaction.user.username}`)


a error returned this  .setAuthor(${interaction.user.username}
^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The error is straight forward seems like you're missing a closing parenthesis for your .setAuthor() function
